# C#: How to deserialize json string to get the same result as webmethod parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, javascriptserializer

now I have some data as below:

```
{"parameters":{"fields":["a","b","c"]}
```

and I use ajax to send the request to .net WebMethod like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Query/Query.asmx/test2?nocache=1',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

})
```

and the WebMethod I used in query.asmx is:

```
[WebMethod]
public string test2(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    return "ok";
}
```

we can see that the `parameters["fields"]` is of type `System.Object[]`

But now I have a requirement to compress the data and decompress it in backend, and the data becomes a string(after decompressed). Now I want to deserialize it to exact the same type as before.

after decompression, the data becomes a JSON string:

```
"{\"parameters\":{\"fields\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}}"
```

Now I want to use JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize it to the same type. But What I can get is `parameters["fields"]` of type `System.Collections.ArrayList` and not the type `System.Object[]` I require.

the code is like below

```
public class TestDataObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> parameters { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var a = serializer.Deserialize<TestDataObject>(d);
```

So the question is: is there a way for me to deserialize it to exactly the same type? I can't use another library since I have got some javascriptSerializer converters implemented for some customized types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `JavascriptSerializer`, there is a method `ConvertToType` which can be used to convert an object to a class instance. After `DeserializeObject()` is called, the result type is exactly what I want. So, the code can be:

```
    var b = serializer.DeserializeObject(d);
    var c = serializer.ConvertToType(b, typeof(TestDataObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change type of value in dictionary to `object[]` instead of `object`:

```
public class TestDataObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, object[]> parameters { get; set; }
}

string json = "{\"parameters\":{\"fields\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var a = serializer.Deserialize<TestDataObject>(json);
a.parameters["fields"].GetType() == typeof(object[]); //equals True
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but in the real case, it has more than one level, I just can't give all nested elements types. sorry I didn't make it clear

Comment: and in 'parameters' there are more than this array-like type. It has some other primitive types and nested object.